# Haskell "Failed to load interface" after changing directory

Tags: haskell, interface, directory, package, ghc

After installing ghc I changed the working directory with

```
:cd /newDirectory
```

For this, I get the warning:

```
Warning: changing directory causes all loaded modules to be unloaded,
because the search path has changed.
```

Now, I cannot use a data type like Char. For this line:

```
map Char.isLower "abcD"
```

I get the message:

```
Failed to load interface for `Char'
It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.2'.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Is the change of directory the reason for that error? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the module (not a data type) `Data.Char`, which defines `isLower`:

```
Prelude> map Data.Char.isLower "abcD"
[True,True,True,False]
```

You can also leave it loaded in GHCi, so that you don't have to specify the module every time you use its functions:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> map isLower "abcD"
[True,True,True,False]
```